# Inserting string data into XML column: 'nil=\"true\"'

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, etl, sql-server-2017

SQL Server 2017

I'm trying to debug and re-engineer an SSIS package which gets string data from a web service, then inserts it into an SQL table (into a column of type XML).

The input string data looks something like this:

```
<InvoiceInfo><acceptedDate nil=\"true\" /><.... more stuff...
```

There is no overall problem with the formation of the data - all terminated correctly and so on.  But SQL Server hates this: nil=\"true\".  When I run the SQL generated by the SSIS package in SSMS, I get this error:

> XML parsing: line 1, character 32, A string literal was expected

There's probably a good reason for this.  I don't know much about XML, but AFAIK this "\" escaping doesn't really belong there.

If I do some pre-processing on the input string, replacing "nil=\"true\"" with a zero-length string, it works.

The most bizarre thing is that, when this same SQL is run in an ExecuteSQL task in the SSIS package, **it works**.  I'm completely mystified.  It's not a problem with implicit type conversion; if I add an explicit CONVERT and run it in SSMS -

```
INSERT INTO TheTable(XMLcolumn) VALUES
(CONVERT(XML,'<InvoiceInfo><acceptedDate nil=\"true\" /><.... more stuff...'))
```

it still fails in the same way.

Two questions:

1. How can this SQL work from SSIS but fail in SSMS?
2. What are these "nil=\"true\"" values doing in the XML?

Comment: `\"` would be the standard way to escape the double quote if the whole thing was parsed as a literal in C#, and also the way the VS debugger chooses to present string literals when viewed internally. The SSIS package may be doing something funky with interpolating the string and executing things dynamically, or else you are interpreting the results wrong. If you want to see *actual* SQL passed, your best bet is always SQL Profiler/extended events.

Comment: The `nil="true"` is likely a way to indicate the element should be stored/interpreted as a `NULL` value rather than an empty string (there is no semantic difference between an empty element and one with no content in XML, so this distinction must be added explicitly); the T-SQL standard way of doing so is adding an `xsi:nil="true"` attribute (note the use of the `xsi` namespace there, typically mapped to `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` in a top-level `xmlns`).

Comment: Thanks.  Profiler was my friend here.  The "\"s are artifacts of the SSIS Watch in VS: the actual SQL passed to the server doesn't have them.  That's why it works!  If you'd like to make that comment into an answer, will accept it with thanks!  Re your second comment: good tip.  The eventual output from this process is full of empty strings rather than NULLs, so that would be the solution.